# Closing Browser window after twitter login android with twitter4J

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

Hi I am developing android application in which I am using twitter login. I am using twitter4j-3.0.5 lib for twitter authentication. So my scene is like this after login successful it come back to my application but in background it is not closing browser window. when I click back my browser with twitter window is still there.

My code looks like this:

```
Intent intent = new  Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL()));
        startActivity(intent);

<activity
    android:name="com.example.twitterapp.TwitterWebActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_twitter_web" >
     <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
        android:host="com.example.twitterapp"
        android:scheme="oauth" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I want to close that web browser. Is there any one can help me please ? Need Help. Than you.

Comment: did u find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

add this:
`intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);` before starting Activity.

Comment: Thank you for response will try this and let you know whether works or not.